# Python details of any method

Tags: python

Is it possible to view, how exactly methods work? For example list method count().
I have a list:

```
li = [3, 5, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3]
```

When I type

```
print li.count(3)
```

The ouptut will be 4. How I can see a code where this magic happens?
Command help(list.count) gives short insufficient info:

```
>>> help(list.count)
Help on method_descriptor:

count(...)
    L.count(value) -> integer -- return number of occurrences of value
```

Comment: `help(list.count)`, read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2173).

Comment: Have you tried Googling Python's source code?

Comment: Yes, I tried to find this code in Google. But I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most builtins are implemented in C, so you won't be able to see the code. You can however get a detailed help to everything with the "help" function.

```
help(li.count)
```

This gives you enough information to really know what things you can do with whatever object you are supplying to the help. What I did when I started out is to write my own functions that emulate the functionality. This gives you a really good grasp of all the things you have to consider.
Here is an example of how a count function could look like:

```
def count(crit, iterable):
    i = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if crit == item:
            i += 1
    return i
```

As an alternative, a lot of things (like the tkinter module) are written in Python and you can look them up in pythonx.x/Lib/tkinter (replace tkinter with whatever module you want to look at).
I hope that answers your question well enough.